# MySQL on update current_timestamp not working

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with a column `updated_at default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp`.

The value for `updated_at` gets updated whenever I update the row with a query (directly or through php code) but whenever the row is updated by a trigger from some other table the `updated_at` value does not change. I want that this also to happen.

Any suggestions? reasons for this problem?

The relevant row of table1

```
Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       
updated_at        | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

The trigger in table2 updates some coloumns in table1 whenever a certain coloumn2 in table2 is updated. NOTE: the timestamp is not updated in the trigger. I expect MySQL to do that automatically.

Also I am using a Master-Slave replication and the problem is on both the master and the slave. The logging format for master slave replication is statement logging.

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple example for timestamp update with triggers:

First you should have two (*simple*) tables:

Table named ***`TriggerTable`***

```
#Field     #Type         #Function
 1  id      int(11)       AUTO_INCREMENT 
 2  data    varchar(52)
```

Table named ***`UpdatesHere`***

```
#Field     #Type         #Function
 1  id      int(11)       AUTO_INCREMENT 
 2  time    timestamp     NOW(), on update NOW()
```

#### Then comes TRIGGER

Add trigger that executes on every `TriggerTable` update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TriggerTableOnUpdate` 
    AFTER UPDATE ON `TriggerTable` 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE `UpdatesHere` SET `time`=NOW() WHERE `id`=NEW.id; 
    END
```

After that if you do update in `TriggerTable` it should update `UpdatesTable` too. It simply updates column with same id.

#### For example:

```sql
UPDATE  `TriggerTable` SET `data`='Hello World' WHERE `id`=1;
```

will update column `time` in row with `id` 1 at table `UpdatesHere`.

***Note:*** Change your delimiter with `DELIMITER [`*`delimiter`*`]` when defining triggers.

Comment: Hey, I wanted a solution where the timestamp of updated at remains in the same table, and the timestamp is updated automatically in MySQL.

Comment: I wanted to explain the problem further. Since the column is set to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` MySQL should automatically update the `updated_at` field each time any field in the row is changed. This happens if I directly change a field value in the table, using a MySQL statement or through some PHP code. The problem is that whenever the value in the field is changed by a trigger on some other table executing, the `updated_at` field does not change automatically.